# Timing text transition with pulsating rings

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

The goal is to have the text transition to 3 different words. I want them to be in sync with the animated rings(text change after every two rings animate fading in and fading out) I'm not sure what is the best way to set the timing for the rings and the text - should this be done with javascript or CSS animation keyframes? Below is a link to my codepen and HTML/CSS.
Codepen - https://codepen.io/pizzapgh/pen/RygPQJ

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
}

#circles {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#circles div {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: growCircles;
  animation-duration: 8s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

#circles div:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

#circles div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

#circles div:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

#circles div:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

#circles div:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

#circles div:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

@keyframes growCircles {
  0% {
    top: 500px;
    left: 500px;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}


/*================================
                  Text Transition
              ================================== */

#spin:after {
  content: "";
  animation: spin 5s ease-in infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    content: "From The Classroom";
  }
  60% {
    content: "To the City";
  }
  100% {
    content: "To the World";
  }
}

h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 6;
  color: white;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'RockwellMT' !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-container">
  <div id="circles">
    <h2 id="spin"></h2>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "in sync with the animated rings?" There's six rings and only three lines of copy, do you want the copy to fade for every two rings?

Comment: Exactly what I want.